# how to close jQuery tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tooltip

I've been trying to make very simple javascript tooltip with jQuery but I've hit a brick wall. The idea is to have little inline element (`span`) inside a `div`. The `span` element will contain a tooltip `div` with a little html (image and link). Tooltip should be opened when clicked on the `span` element and closed when clicked outside of it or outside of the tooltip.

So far, opening the tooltip is not a problem but closing is.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style>
        #colors > div {
            background-color: red;
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            margin: 5px;
        }

        #colors > div > span {
            min-height: 10px !important;
            min-width: 10px !important;
            border: 3px solid black;
            position: relative;
        }

        .tooltip {
            border: 2px solid blue;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            // generate boxes and tooltips
            for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                $('#colors').append('<div id="' + i + '"><span><div class="tooltip"><a href="#">add to favorites</a></div></span></div>');
            }

            $('#colors').delegate('span', 'click', function (event) {
                $(this).children('.tooltip').css({position:'absolute', top:'5px', left:'5px'}).fadeIn();
                // bottom one won't work
                //event.stopPropagation();
            });

            $(document).delegate('body', 'click', function (event) {
                var that = this
                $.each($('.tooltip'), function (index, element) {
                    // it's always visible ...
                    //if ($(element).is(':visible')) {

                    // doesn't work either
                    if ($(element).is(':visible') && $(element).has(event.target).length === 0) {
                        var s = event.target;

                        console.log([($(s) == event.target), event.target, index, element, $(element).has(event.target).length, that]);
                    }
                });
            });
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="colors"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't seem to find a way to close the tooltip if click is outside of the `span` and tooltip.

Comment: Editing your question is not the correct way to let people know your problem is solved. Accepting an answer would be the correct way. If you solved your problem in a different way then the current answers please provide an answer yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work fine :)

```
 $(document).mouseup(function (e)
 {
     var container = $("YOUR CONTAINER SELECTOR");

     if (container.has(e.target).length === 0)
     {
        container.hide();
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 6):

To close a tooltip you need to call

```
$('.tooltip').remove();
```

In your scenario try

```
$.each($('.tooltip'), function (index, element) {
    $(this).remove();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I investigated this issue for my own site and didn't find any suitable solution, so I wrote my own. My use case is a bit different to the OPs, but might help other people searching for the same term. I needed a close link that **only appears on mobile platforms**. This is useful because on a desktop, the tool tip will close when you `mouseout` from the target element, but on a touch platform it sticks around.

```
// Set up tool tips for images and anchors.
$( document ).tooltip({
  items: "a[title], img[alt], .toolTip[title], :not(.noToolTip)",
    track: true,
    position: { my: "left+15 center", at: "right center" },
   content: function() {
      var element = $( this );
      var closer = closerLink = '';
      if (isMobile()) {
         closer = ' <br><div onClick="$(this).parent().parent().remove();" style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline; text-align: right;">Close</div>';
         closerLink = ' <br>Tap link again to open it.<br><div onClick="$(this).parent().parent().remove();" style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline; text-align: right;">Close</div>';
      }
      // noToolTip means NO TOOL TIP.
      if ( element.is( ".noToolTip" ) ) {
         return null;
      }
      // Anchor - use title.
      if ( element.is( "a[title]" ) ) {
         return element.attr( "title" ) + closerLink;
      }
      // Image - use alt.
      if ( element.is( "img[alt]" ) ) {
         return element.attr( "alt" ) + closer;
      }
      // Any element with toolTip class - use title.
      if ( element.is( ".toolTip[title]" ) ) {
         return element.attr( "title" ) + closer;
      }
   }
});

function isMobile() {
   return (/iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry/).test(navigator.userAgent);
}
```

I am targeting three types of things here:

- Anchor tags (`a`) with a `title` attribute.
- Image tags (`img`) with a `title` attribute.
- Any element with class `toolTip`.
- And specifically *exclude* any element with class `noToolTip`.

I wrote this up here: [JQuery UI tooltip with a close link for mobile](http://robertmarkbramprogrammer.blogspot.com.au/2015/06/jquery-ui-tooltip-with-close-link-for.html)

Answer (score 1):

When you generate the tooltips, save the result to a variable. You can use it after to close all the tooltips.

```
var tooltips = $(document).tooltip({
    // all kind of initilization options like position, open, hide, etc.
});

// ... app logic ...

tooltips.tooltip('close') // will close all tooltips
```

had the info from here: https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#forms

Answer (score -3):

```
 $(document).mouseup(function (kamesh)
 {
     var container = $("YOUR CONTAINER SELECTOR");

     if (container.has(kamesh.target).length === 0)
     {
        container.hide();
     }
 });
```

Comment: Please try to add a little more information to your answers.