# Hiding tooltip on button click in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a tooltip but it fails to hide on button click.

This is my button :

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-inverse ajax_addtocart additems                                                                             
         data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to cart"                                                                                         
         id="<?php echo $item->id ?>">
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
    <span class="select_options">Add to cart</span>
</button>
```

This is the button click :

```
$("button.additems").click(function(e){ //user clicks form submit button
    e.preventDefault();
    var button = $(this);
    var form_data = $(this).attr("id"); //prepare form data for Ajax post
    button.prop('disabled', true); //Loading button text //change button text

     .............. Continues to do ajax after ajax request
 button.prop('disabled', false)
```

The tootltip stays displayed.

I have tried adding

```
button.tooltip('hide')   //this also fails
```

I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840885/how-to-close-jquery-tooltip) and

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a jQuery UI [`tooltip`](https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip), have you tried the [`close`](https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#method-close) method?

```
button.tooltip('close');
```